# How do I perform a mongodb two phase commit in grails?

Tags: java, mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm working on a system that used mongodb. For a specific case, I'm required to be able to rollback saves. How do I go on doing using GORM?

Comment: two phase commit in MongoDB is not atomic, if you want that then you will need a tech that actually supports it

Comment: @Sammaye I just wanna be able to rollback.

Comment: Ok that should be doable in maybe 85% of application/database failures, though do bare in mind that two phase commits are not server side so there will be some cases where the application might run into inconsistencies still. Anyway I thought I would just get that point across to make you more aware of the situation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed the instructions at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits. My code looks like:

```
FinancialTransaction financialTransaction = createFinancialTransaction(transactionType, amount, from, to,
             process)

        financialTransaction = financialTransaction.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        financialTransaction.transactionStatus = FinancialTransactionStatusEnum.PENDING
        financialTransaction = financialTransaction.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)


        def transactionLineNumber = 1
        financialTransaction.addToTransactionItems( new FinancialTransactionItem(financialAccount: from.financialAccount, 
            transactionLineNumber: transactionLineNumber++, debitAmount: amount, creditAmount: 0,
            description: "Money debited from Unions account for loan." ))
        financialTransaction.addToTransactionItems( new FinancialTransactionItem(financialAccount: to.financialAccount,
            transactionLineNumber: transactionLineNumber++, creditAmount: amount, debitAmount: 0, 
            description: "Money credited to Coops account from a loan received from a Union." ))

        financialTransaction.save( flush: true, failOnError: true)

        financialTransaction.transactionItems.each()  { transactionItem -> 
                    financialAccount = transactionItem.financialAccount


                if( financialAccount.pendingTransactions.contains(financialTransaction.id )) //transaction has been committed to this account(used during recovery)
                    return

                delta = (transactionItem.debitAmount == 0) ? transactionItem.creditAmount : transactionItem.debitAmount
                sign = (transactionItem.debitAmount == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0
                newBalance = financialAccount.totalBalance + delta * sign

                financialAccount.totalBalance = newBalance
                financialAccount.pendingTransactions << financialTransaction.id

                financialAccount.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

                if(log.isDebugEnabled())
                        log.debug("Saved Financial Account Id: ${transactionItem.financialAccount.id} Balance: ${newBalance}")

                new FinancialAccountChange(financialAccount: financialAccount, updatedBalance: newBalance,
                    delta: delta * sign, financialTransactionItem: transactionItem).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        }

        financialTransaction.transactionStatus = FinancialTransactionStatusEnum.COMMITTED
        financialTransaction = financialTransaction.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        financialTransaction.transactionItems*.financialAccount.each { fA ->
            fA.pendingTransactions - financialTransaction.id
            fA.save( flush: true, failOnError: true )           
        }

        financialTransaction.transactionStatus = FinancialTransactionStatusEnum.DONE
        financialTransaction = financialTransaction.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```